# How to add swipe event on elements in angular4?

Tags: angular

i'm trying to add a swipe event to elements on a page to trigger a class change but nothing i've tried so far works.
I'm working with Angular 4 . 
Any idea of a library i could use ?
I've heard about Hammerjs but i don't know if that could do the job.

Thanks.

Comment: Please give examples of what you have tried so far

Comment: There is no such a thing as a swipe event in Javascript, you can use `onmousedown` and `onmousemove` to simulate it though

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding hammerjs does provide gesture support.  Something like this article may help you get started: https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-hammerjs-touch-gesture-in-angular-2.  Even though it is for Angular 2 the concepts should still be valid for 4.